# Download images requested latest with high prority than images which were requested earlier

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is there a way to load some images with high priority than the other requested resources.

This higher priority images are requested when the user presses some button on the page & since there are already some resources which the client has been downloading since previous time, this image's download is quite delayed. There is long time lapse before the image is requested by the client from the server.

How do I set high priority for this **new request** resources ?

---

*(I have a long page containing several slideshows. Initially only 1st image of slideshow is requested(& other images later, when `Next` is pressed) but still, page loading takes some time, so I want that when next is pressed for any slideshow, it should prioritize downloading the images of that slideshow first instead of completing to download the first images of all slideshows on the page.)*

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you want. The only suggestion I can think of, is to cut down the number of slide shows on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to preload your images on pageload.

Comment: preloading all images will slow down the webpage as the albums are big

Comment: Than try to load on an other event, so not onClick but onHover for example, so it will start download before click. Or you can try to write a function to append your images in hidden. The function loads an image, after load a callback comes where it downloads the next image, etc... This way you can order your image downloads, but you need an array of your images name for ex.